# Salesforce to Outlook Connector - File Synching

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

We are seeing the following behavior.

If we have an appointment in Outlook and if it has an attachment and when the "Salesforce to Outlook" synch happens, the appointment gets created in Salesforce but the attachment from Outlook is not created in Salesforce.

Similarly, if an appointment is created with attachment in Salesforce and when the synch is triggered, the appointment gets created in Outlook but the attachment from Salesforce is not created in Outlook.

Is this expected ?.
Are there any settings that we can set that can change this behavior ?